# Catch two types of warning

Tags: python, scikit-learn, warnings

So I want to catch different types of warnings on the following code:

```
score = cross_val_score(DecisionTreeClassifier(), X, y, scoring=f2_measure, cv=cv)
```

From running the code, I got two warnings:

```
UserWarning: The least populated class in y has only 1 members, which is less than n_splits=2.
  % (min_groups, self.n_splits)), UserWarning)

UndefinedMetricWarning: F-score is ill-defined and being set to 0.0 due to no true nor predicted samples. 
  Use `zero_division` parameter to control this behavior.
```

I'd like to catch both type of warnings and then handle them separately, I tried using the following:

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings('error', category=UserWarning)
    warnings.filterwarnings('error', category=UndefinedMetricWarning)
    try:
        score = cross_val_score(DecisionTreeClassifier(), X, y, scoring=f2_measure, cv=cv).mean()
    except (UndefinedMetricWarning, UserWarning) as e:
        print(type(e))
```

But all of the warnings are then raised as a `UserWarning`, and there's no `UndefinedMetricWarning`.  (I'm not quite sure but I think this problem might be caused by `UndefinedMetricWarning` is inherited from `UserWarning`).

How to identify and handle these two type of warnings separately?

Comment: Checking the code, `UndefinedMetricWarning` is indeed inherited from `UserWarning`

Answer (score 2):

You can use two different `except`s after your `try`. The second `except` will catch only the exceptions that are not caught by the first `except`. So you can make the first `except` catch the subclass `UndefinedMetricWarning` and then the second `except` can effectively catch only the `UserWarning` warnings that are not also an `UndefinedMetricWarning`:

```
with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.filterwarnings('error', category=UserWarning)
    warnings.filterwarnings('error', category=UndefinedMetricWarning)
    try:
        score = cross_val_score(DecisionTreeClassifier(), X, y, scoring=f2_measure, cv=cv).mean()
    except UndefinedMetricWarning as e:
        print(type(e))
    except UserWarning as e:
        print(type(e))
```

Here is a minimal working example:

```
import warnings

class MyWarning(UserWarning):
    pass

def a(flag):
    if flag:
        warnings.warn("hello", MyWarning)
    else:
        warnings.warn("bye")

def b(flag):
    with warnings.catch_warnings():
        warnings.filterwarnings("error", category=UserWarning)
        warnings.filterwarnings("error", category=MyWarning)
        try:
            a(flag)
        except MyWarning as e:
            print(type(e))
        except UserWarning as e:
            print(type(e))

b(True)
b(False)
```

See: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html